# Limiting Eloquent many-to-many relationship by category type

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to create a website in Laravel that uses a single categories table for multiple entities, in a many-to-many relationship. I have tried polymorphism, but it only works one way, and I need to be able to query the following:

- A list of all service categories
- A list of all article categories
- A list of all categories that a service/article is in
- A list of all services/articles in a category

This is the database structure below. As you can see, there is a type column in categories that allows me to select either service or article as the category type.

[image: schema]

I've got the general idea working very well, but I need to ensure that the application does not allow types of category to be accidentally mixed. I was under the impression that the following code would do this:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service')->where('type', '=', 'service')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article')->where('type', '=', 'article')->withTimestamps();
    }         
}
class Service extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->where('type', '=', 'service')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
class Article extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->where('type', '=', 'article')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

As I had read in the documentation that adding a `where` after the `belogsToMany` would restrict it. It doesn't.

I insert the following data:

```
id  name            type    created_at          updated_at
1   Category One    service 2016-01-31 13:23:29 2016-01-31 13:23:29
2   Category Two    article 2016-01-31 13:24:02 2016-01-31 13:24:02

id  name        created_at          updated_at
1   Service One 2016-01-31 13:23:10 2016-01-31 13:23:10
```

And then run this query:

```
$category = App\Category::find(2);
$category->services()->attach(1);
```

And it works perfectly, despite the fact it is attaching a service to a category of type 'article'. It should not be inserting this data.

How do I get the restriction to work correctly?

Comment: I would use a scope applied to the relationship. Gives more flexibility that way

Comment: @MikeMiller How does that work, in this context?

Comment: I'm on my phone but it looks like you should create a common model class to inherit. Inside this put a couple of scope functions (check docs, not hard) as these seem to be common to a couple of models. The docs also show how to apply a scope to a relationship. If this looks like it might work post some working code I will do my to help out

Comment: @MikeMiller Would that allow me to prevent inserting an article from succeeding if the type of category is set as `service`? Basically that's what I'm going for, an innate restriction built into the models to prevent the types of category being mixed. That's all I need, really.